# I'm having a trouble getting user information using its foreign_key from other table (PHP, LARAVEL, MYSQL)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to follow this tutorial on YouTube -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE&t=9092s but stuck at 2:30:57.

[Here's the prompt error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsZvZ.png)

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException

Call to undefined method App\Post::belongTo() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\test3\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)

http://localhost:8000/p/5

And these are the files that i think involve in the error.

1.) show.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
   <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="w-100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
   <div>
    <h3>
     {{ $post->user->username }} <!-- Here, I can't get the USERNAME of the owner of the 'post'. -->


     </h3>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
@endsection('content')
```

2.) PostController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class PostController extends Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  $this->middleware('auth');
 }

 public function create()
 {
  return view('posts/create');
 }

 public function store()
 {

  $data = request()->validate([
   'caption' => 'required',
   'image' => 'required|image', //you can either use this = ['required', 'image']
  ]);

   $image_path = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

   $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/$image_path"))->fit(1200, 1200);
   $image->save();


   auth()->user()->posts()->create([
    'caption' => $data['caption'],
    'image' => $image_path,
   ]);


   return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
 }

 public function show(\App\Post $post)
 {
  return view('posts/show', compact('post'));
 }
}
```

3.) Post.php

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
 protected $guarded = [];
    public function user()
    {
     return $this->belongTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

I'm new to laravel so maybe I did something I don't understand and was not able to detect where the problem lies.
Hoping I could get some insight on this. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Bryan!
The method is clear: `Call to undefined method App\Post::belongTo()`
If you carefully go through the documentation, you'll see that the method is actually `belongsTo`, with an S.
Try that again and let us know if it works.

Comment: Yeah, it was also my fault not able to understand this. I already solve this as this was just a typo error. btw thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: please check in $post the user id exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Sir Victor, the one who create the YouTube Tutorial. With his fast response, he pointed out where my problem lies.

It was just a quick typo in the method call. It should be belongsTo() you just forgot the s.

I'll just leave it here to remind some that check their code for possibilities of typo errors :)

Also, some instruction/s is still welcome. :) Thank you for reading.